# Mongoid, find object by searching by part of the Id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to be able to search for my objects by searching for the last 4 characters of the id. How can I do that?

```
Book.where(_id: params[:q])
```

Where the param would be something like `a3f4`, and in this case the actual id for the object that I want to be found would be:

```
bc313c1f5053b66121a8a3f4
```

Notice the last for characters are what we searched for. How can I search for just "part" of my objects id? instead of having my user search manually by typing in the *entire* id?

I found in MongoDB's help docs, that I can provide a regex:

```
db.x.find({someId : {$regex : "123\\[456\\]"}}) // use "\\" to escape
```

Is there a way for me to search using the regular mongo ruby driver and not using Mongoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, in Mongoid you can search with a regexp like you normally would with a string in your call to `where()` ie:

```
Book.where(:title => /^Alice/) # returns all books with titles starting with 'Alice'
```

However this doesn't work in your case, because the `_id` field is not stored as a string, but as an ObjectID. However, you could add (and index) a field on your models which could provide this functionality for you, which you can populate in an `after_create` callback.

`<shameless_plug>`

Alternatively, if you're just looking for a shorter solution to the default Mongoid IDs, I could suggest something like [mongoid_token](https://github.com/thetron/mongoid_token) which makes it pretty easy to add shorter tokens/ids to your Mongoid documents.

`</shameless_plug>`

Comment: I like your gem! I'm going to use it! I feel like its a little bit overkill for the needs I have, but it looks awesome